# Color name or number not recognized with User1-9

Tags: highlight, error

When I run `highlight User1 ctermbg=#505050 ctermfg=#d0d0d0 gui=italic`, I get the following error.

```
E421: Color name or number not recognized: ctermbg=#505050 ctermfg=#d0d0d0 gui=italic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#xxyyzz` is invalid value for `ctermbg` and `ctermfg`. It can only be used for `guifg` and `guibg`.

If your terminal has support for TrueColor then do `set termguicolors` and set guixx params instead.